# Allow To Specific Text For Replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I try to create something like this:

If in HTML, find `{{heart}}` text, then replace that with font awesome heart.

> {{heart}} => fa fa-heart

In this code (below), you can use a CSS class.

Example: you can use something like this : `{{heart red}}`

But I don't like that!

I want to create something like rule, so that you can use just: `{{heart}}`, `{{star}}`, `{{apple}}`.

and if you try to use another that, it won't work.

Something like a 2d array:

> {{heart}} => fa fa-heart,
>
> {{star}} => fa fa-star,
>
> etc.

I have this code:

```html
 $(document).ready(function(){
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\{{([^}]+)}}/g, '<i class="fa fa-$1"></i>');
});
```

Comment: Your snippet isn't doing anything when you click Run code snippet, since you don't have any HTML in your example. So it's hard to tell what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy method would be to use the browser itself to do all the parsing and matching.

create an element that will not be appended to the dom

check if the element has the class name, if not append it to the class name

finally return the outerhtml string of the element

Snippet below

```js
function class_detector(classnames, html) {
  //chrome you need to place el in parent in order to set html
  var parent = document.createElement("div");
  var el = document.createElement("i");
  parent.appendChild(el);
  el.outerHTML = html;
  for (var x = 0; x < classnames.length; ++x) {
    if (!el.classList.contains("fa-" + classnames[x])) {
      el.classList.add("fa-" + classnames[x])
    }
  }

  return el.outerHTML;;;
}

var output = class_detector(["apple", "pear"], '<i class="fa another-class></i>')
console.log(output);;
```

Comment: Sure like those semicolons, don't you? :). Also, your snippet fails with an error about not being able to set the outerHTML property because the element has no parent node. You're probably better off using a DocumentFragment or something.

Comment: snippet works on mozilla...what browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome 57 Windows 10.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You are right!.. for chrome the element must be in parent container...I did the edit!

Comment: Nice. I've always gone by the edict "treat `outerHTML` as read-only". Use `innerHTML` all you want, but setting the `outerHTML` you make the original element reference potentially invalid. For example, you create your `i` element, but then set `outerHTML` to "<a href="something.html"></a>". Is it valid to set the `href` property? The browser doesn't know because the original reference doesn't point to an `HTMLAnchorElement`. Minor issue on a fine answer.